# What is a good and efficient algorithm for a content based recommender?

Tags: machine-learning, large-data, recommender-system, heuristic

I want to build a content based recommender in a restricted environment regarding cpu power and memory (to be specific: a mobile device, but it is not acceptable to build the recommender on a remote server).

Which algorithm or heuristic is feasible in such a situation ?

Comment: Do the analysis remotely and send back the results.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the reply, what i actually need is to do the computation on the device itself. I have edited the question as well.

Comment: What does the data looks like ? It's only item features or do you have collaborative data from multiple users ? In the latter case, you have to somehow sync them in one place in order to build a recommender. Or does the system works P2P and everyone stores everything of all other connected users ?

Comment: Steffen, thanks for the response, the data is structured. It would be a content based filtering method as collaborative filtering would really slow any mobile device down as the number of users increase.

Comment: @Shashank aaaah, now we are getting somewhere. So it is basically a content based recommender with the owner / user of the device being the only one which provides explicit feedback / rating ?

Comment: Did you need any element connected or a database inside with multiple probabilities for getting a similarity.
If you have a connections with other devices via bluetooth or nfc you can change a token with the profile and getting a first step for getting a similarity, is important to know the context of the elements needs to be same but results are know for the two devices. If yo don't have any connection with the world you need a database, a tree with multiple feelings, words, or ranking and getting a recommendation based in a similarities compared with your profile and artificial tree.

Comment: @Shashank I have edited the question according to my understanding of your comments. Please check if I have changed accidentically the meaning. Additionally, it would help (and increase the quality of the question) if you would provide sample data and the size (since you have mentioned big / large data)

Comment: @Steffen thanks for the editing, it sums up what am i looking for. As for the sample data I currently don't have an estimate. I am currently trying to figure out whether such a system is feasible or not with a certain degree of correctness in terms of the recommendations. Could you please provide an estimate for the size of the data.

Comment: I don't know how small is small, and how much processing power you have. But I would model this as a supervised learning problem with linear predictors. Use squared error and mini-batch gradient descent. Please note that you should only use terms which have ratings to calculate your cost. But this is the smallest such model I can think of. For best results, start with an offline trained model (good weights) and refine it within this context.